# Issue faced while installing m2e on eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, rad, m2e-wtp

Followed the below steps:(RAD 8.0.4)

- Go to help – Install new software.
- In the Available Software page of the install wizard, click the Add button next to Work with field and add this new location: 
  @download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2eclipse-wtp/
- Click on Available Software Sites link and verify that only the checkboxes for the following sites are selected. Then click OK.

  - m2eclipse-wtp updates http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2eclipse-wtp/
  - Eclipse Project Test Site @download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6
  - The Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP) software repository

@download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/helios

- In the Work With field of the Available Software page, select: m2eclipse-wtp updates.
- Under the Name column, select the following check boxes:

  - m2e connector for mavenarchiver pom properties
  - Maven Integration for WTP.

The following error occurred.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e connector for mavenarchiver pom properties 0.15.0.201212080009 (org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.feature.feature.group 0.15.0.201212080009)
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.4.0.20130601-0317) requires 'bundle org.slf4j.api 1.6.2' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.1.20140328-1905 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.4.1.20140328-1905) requires 'bundle org.slf4j.api 1.6.2' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.5.0.20140606-0033 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.5.0.20140606-0033) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.7.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.jdt 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core [1.4.0,1.5.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT 1.4.1.20140328-1905 (org.eclipse.m2e.jdt 1.4.1.20140328-1905)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core [1.4.0,1.5.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT 1.5.0.20140606-0033 (org.eclipse.m2e.jdt 1.5.0.20140606-0033)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core [1.5.0,1.6.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e connector for the mavenarchiver and pom properties 0.15.0.201212080009 (org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver 0.15.0.201212080009)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.m2e.jdt [1.0.0,2.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e connector for mavenarchiver pom properties 0.15.0.201212080009 (org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.feature.feature.group 0.15.0.201212080009)
    To: org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver [0.15.0.201212080009]
```

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar issue, and managed to install m2e using indigo update site: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/

- Go to help – Install new software.
- Add... pick a name with the above URL as Location.
- Once the list loads, under "General Purpose Tools", check "m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse    ".
- Continue with the installation & restart.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

FOR INDIGO:

1) Install the m2e v1.3 using the url: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3

(Select the latest 1.3 version)

2) Then install to m2e v 1.4 using : http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

(Select the latest 1.4 version)